# Symfony/PhpUnit - How to test that an Exception is throws or not in a Service

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm beginner with tests and I want to test my `ValidatorService` which throws an `InvalidDataException` when an entity data are not valid.

My **ValidatorServiceTest** function :

```
    public function testValidatorForUser()
    {
        $validatorMock = $this->createMock(ValidatorInterface::class);
        $contraintViolationMock = $this->createMock(ConstraintViolationListInterface::class);

        $validatorMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('validate')
            ->with()
            ->willReturn($contraintViolationMock);

        $validatorService = new ValidatorService($validatorMock);
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail('test');

        $validatorService->validate($user);
        $this->expectException(InvalidDataException::class);
    }
```

My **ValidatorService** :

```
class ValidatorService
{
    /**
     * @var ValidatorInterface
     */
    private ValidatorInterface $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @param null $constraints
     * @param null $groups
     * @throws InvalidDataException
     */
    public function validate($value, $constraints = null, $groups = null)
    {
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($value, $constraints, $groups);

        if (count($errors) > 0) {
            throw new InvalidDataException($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

My **User** entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", errorPath="email", message="user.email.unique")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", errorPath="username", message="user.username.unique")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private ?int $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @JMS\Groups({"api"})
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.email.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Email(message="user.email.email")
     */
    private string $email;

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.password.not_blank")
     * @Assert\Length(min=8, minMessage="user.password.length.min")
     */
    private string $password;

    /**
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="user.confirm_password.not_blank")
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="password", message="user.confirm_password.equal_to")
     */
    private string $confirmPassword;

   ...
   ...
```

I have this **error** :

```
1) App\Tests\Service\Validator\ValidatorServiceTest::testValidatorForUser
Failed asserting that exception of type "App\Exception\InvalidDataException" is thrown.
```

How can I test if an exception thows or not ?

Comment: Swap the call to `validate() ` & `expectException()` in the test - you can't expect something if it's already happened.

Comment: I have the same error.

Comment: I've duplicated your code and test as best I can - and you don't have any errors being made, $errors is empty, and so nothing is thrown.

Comment: I updated the main post and added `User` entity. And I tried directly with `$validator = self::$container->get(ValidatorInterface::class); $errors = $validator->validate($user)` and $errors is not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

The problem was with my `$contraintViolationMock` which always returned empty data.
I have to retrieve violations before and test that it's match with the mock violations. I think, it's the more simple solution instead of creating manually a `ConstraintViolationList`.
If you have a better solution, i'll take it.

```
    public function testValidatorForUser()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail('test');
        $validator = self::$container->get(ValidatorInterface::class);
        $violations = $validator->validate($user);

        $validatorMock = $this->createMock(ValidatorInterface::class);

        $validatorMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('validate')
            ->willReturn($violations);

        $this->expectException(InvalidDataException::class);

        $validatorService = new ValidatorService($validatorMock);
        $validatorService->validate($user);
    }
```